# How to print dict sorted by keys?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, serialization, dictionary

My use case involves printing a json. To aid legibility I want to print it sorted by key. `dict` comes into the picture as in my case `json.loads` returns a `dict`.

Things I tried:

1. `dict.__str__ = myStrFn` which results in `TypeError: can't set
       attributes of built-in/extension type 'dict'`
2. Write `myDict` along the lines of
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/931822/438758. This does not work for
   nested dictionaries as the nested dictionaries are of type `dict`
   and not `myDict`.

What are my options here? I would prefer something which makes `print(json.loads(json_str))` work. But would settle for `print(str_func(json.loads(json_str)))`.

If you have a solution specific to my json use case, that would be great too. But I would prefer a generic answer. I am aware that `dict` keys only need to be `hashable` and not "comparable" (in the sense that there might not be a total order), so an absolutely generic solution might not be possible. But I am inclined to believe that we can have a solution for all valid JSON types.

I am using `python3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print(json.dumps(your_dict, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: That was quick. Thank you.

Comment: Note that this fails for types which aren't serializable to JSON, such as `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: @uckelman: Indeed. In this case, the original input *was* JSON, and the questioner described his problem as "printing a json", which is why I felt printing JSON was appropriate. If the original hadn't been JSON, I would only have suggested this as an alternate solution, since JSON syntax isn't entirely compatible with Python syntax.